# Method in schema is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I don't know why trying to use a scheme method i get that the method name is not a function and i don´t get why because i can´t find any typo and the function itself is just a simple console log.
My schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const addressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  street: String,
  city: String,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    minLenght: 10,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: {
      validator: (v) => v.includes("@gmail.com") !== false,
      message: (props) => `${props.value} does not contain valide domain`,
    },
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
    immutable: true,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
  hobbies: [String],
  address: addressSchema,
});

userSchema.methods.sayHi = function () {
  console.log(`Hi ${this.email}`);
};

userSchema.statics.findByName = function () {
  return this.where({ name: new RegExp(name, "i") });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

And the place where i use this schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./User");

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost/testdb",
  () => {
    console.log("Server is up");
  },
  (err) => console.log(err)
);

async function run() {
  try {
    const user = await User.where("age").gt(20);
    console.log(user);
    user.sayHi();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

run();
```